# Script can not write into dierectory

Tags: linux, fedora, apache-httpd, perl, webserver

I have configured apache web server on fedora 29  , perl script that generates web page with current  NIC information (state , speed , mac , etc.) and traffic graph. Script generates the web page and shows the information about the interface but the graphic can not be visualized  .When I run it in the terminal generates the graphic and saves it into the dedicated dir, but when I run the script via HTML button it's not working.
error_log says `ERROR: Could not save png to '/var/www/grafika/graphHour.png'`.
User `angel` and group `apache` have `rwx`  , "others" have `r-x`to all directories and files.

---

Directories' permissions :

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 angel apache 110 Dec 27 15:47 cgi-bin
drwxrwxr-x. 2 angel apache  94 Dec 27 15:47 grafika
drwxr-xr-x. 2 angel apache  41 Dec 23 18:26 html
```

---

Script's permission:

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 angel apache 2323 Dec 27 15:47 networkPage.cgi
```

---

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled (`getenforce`)?  If so, have you created rules to allow web apps to write to this directory?

Comment: Not exactly ,I've tried to make it in permissive mode just for test , and  did not work .

Comment: Does a file with the same path & name already exist from manual testing, where the permissions would prevent over-writing it?

Comment: No , i deleted the files  that were created .